# Modal-style programming within a Java server

Tags: java, modal-dialog

For my game, I have it running on two servers (one for the game, one for the login system). They both need to interact with each other, and sometimes, ask questions about the state of something else in the other server.

For this example, the game server will be asking the login server if a player is trying to log in:

```
public boolean isLoggingIn(int accountId) {
//Form a packet to send.
int retVal = sendData();
return retVal > 0;
}
```

Obviously I'd use an int so information other than booleans can be returned.

My question is, how do I get this modal-style programming working? It'd work just like JFileChooser's getOpenDialog() function.

Also, I should mention that more than one thread can call this method at once.

Comment: How would you define a "modal-style programming"?

Comment: It would be a type of programming language that waits for something else to return before returning itself. I'm not sure if that even makes sense, but basically, how JFileChooser operates.

Comment: In a game server, you usually don't really want it to work like that, because things can't stop and wait for a single user. You probably want to use asynchronous requests. Also, I think you mean JFileChooser.showOpenDialog.

Comment: Maybe it would help most if you describe how your server interacts with users in general. Does each user have a persistent connection? Is there a thread that goes along with that connection? Is the user communicating via HTTP, plain TCP, or some other protocol?

Comment: Each user is connected via a thread within MINA. The two servers talk with each other via plain TCP over a socket.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by modal, you mean trying to block all actions except one. I strongly suspect that this style will lead you into trouble. Modal interaction is a form of locking and therefore not very tolerant to hangups and disconnects and such. To make it tolerant, you need timeouts and cleanup code for cases when someone entered a mode and then nothing further happened. (i.e they closed their laptop, or the game crashed, they unplugged the network cable etc).

If I were you I would instead try to think of things in terms of authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like this on a thread that is supposed to handle other requests after it, it would hang up all those requests while it is blocking for a return value if the latency between the game and login servers is high. Certainly what you want instead is a callback so that your thread could handle other requests while it waits for a response.

I see no reason to halt execution of a thread until a value is received. If you need the value for an operation after it, then just copy all the code you have after the call you want to be "modal" in the callback. If you expect to send multiple requests while still waiting for a response, then send a unique "responseId" from the requester's side that the responder can include in its response. Use the "responseId" as a key for a Map with Runnables as values. When you receive a response, call remove on the Map with the responseId key and call run() on the Runnable value that is returned. MINA is supposed to asynchronous and should not block for a response packet.

If you have a really good reason for why you want to handle it all on the same thread, you can look into the java.util.concurrent package. I would implement it using a CountDownLatch of count 1, call await() after sending a request message, and call countDown() when you receive a response by MINA. You have to use an AtomicReference or an array of length 1 to hold the value you received in the response that you can read back into the waiting thread.

PS, you still doing MapleStory work?

Comment: I thought about callbacks, but couldn't think of a proper way to implement them. A ton of the networking doesn't even need callbacks, but for some functions, they're required to return a boolean or int (for if a character is online, how many characters are online, etc.) And yeah, this is actually for my MapleStory server I'm working on.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to replace OdinMS' RMI calls with something a bit more lightweight? Trying to emulate RMI's behavior from scratch is rather difficult.

Comment: Actually, I'm building a server from scratch. I felt like OdinMS was very out of date, and rather than constantly adding onto it, it would be better to just start from scratch. So far everything's good, it's just stuff like requesting a check if a user is online that I'm hung up on.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer - you need to expose methods on both servers as RMI-capable, and simply invoke methods like you described.

You might find it useful to review the official Oracle RMI tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html

Althought your design might be wrong - it's your design, and why not letting you shoot your head? ;)

Also, it's worth looking at Spring Security: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/